# Credit line is high on one card, low on another: should I lower before raising?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score, credit, credit-limit

Assume that:

- I opened card A a long time ago and card B recently (different institutions).
- I have a very high credit limit on credit card A and a very low one on credit card B.
- I do not need the former but I do need the latter. (When I tried to go over my limit, B was declined.)
- I have a decent credit score, make payments on time, and don't have credit problems in general.

So I want to raise my limit on B, but to ensure it will be approved, I have no idea whether it's better to lower my limit on A first since my current combined credit line might be too high, or whether I should avoid that since my utilization will rise. I'm also not sure if the fact that I opened B recently affects this.

In what cases should I lower my credit limit on A before raising it on B? In particular:

- (When) would it help with whether B will get approved?
- (When) would it help reduce the hit to my credit score (since B would result in a hard pull)?

And if lowering A affects the effects of raising B, around how long should I wait between the two?

Comment: Why do you need the card with the lower limit?

Comment: @BrenBarn: Different features/benefits

Answer (score 1):

Higher total credit capacity (sum of all your credit limits) is a good thing for your credit rating and in the eyes of your credit card company.  **Definitely do not lower your limit on the other card**--this will be counterproductive.

If you want to game the system, make a payment on any outstanding cards so your utilization is super low.  When the payments clear, then apply for the increased limit in B while your credit rating is artificially high.

Generically, if you want guidance on how to improve your credit rating, try using [CreditKarma](http://www.creditKarma.com) and/or [Quizzle](http://www.quizzle.com).  They will do soft pulls, evaluate the various factors influencing your credit, and give you advice on how to improve it.  For free.

When you ask B for an increase, they will look at your credit score, how long you have been with them (and how long since the last increase), and your reported income (and expenses, if they ask for them).  These are the things you should look to improve before asking.

Comment: So are you saying B doesn't care what my credit limits are on my other cards? Or that it does, but I can't do anything to help that?

Comment: I'm saying B wants your credit limits on other cards to be high.  B isn't trying to limit your overall credit capacity; it is trying to avoid being the one lender who trusts you while others do not.  Having high limits on other cards indicates that B is not sticking its neck out in dangerous territory.

Comment: @Mehrdad B absolutely cares what your total available limit is relative to your stated income.  If you just opened the B line and your income hasn't changed since you opened the account, it's not likely that B will approve a line increase without your total available credit changing.

Comment: @quid: OK so that directly contradicts this answer... post another answer? (farnsy: any thoughts on this counterargument?)

Comment: @Mehrdad I recently got the CSR card and had to adjust the available limit from my other Chase card in order to make the CSR useful as my daily card. My total available limit is about 100% of my annual income and my utilization is negligible. And think logically, if B wasn't trying to limit it's exposure why wouldn't B have at least matched the limit of A when it issued the card?  If you've had B for at least 90 days I would simply request the increase from B and go from there, there is no point trying to guess the outcome.

Comment: @quid: I mean it made sense to me that it might matter, that's why I asked in the first place. I've done something similar to what you did within the same company, too, though with my cash credit limit rather than purchase credit limit. On the other hand since it's not the same company I have the other card with, I could believe it if lowering the other one wouldn't change anything. (And I haven't had B for 90 days.)

Comment: @Mehrdad, I'd call them and ask.  Say you were just approved but the limit isn't serviceable as your daily card.  You'd like to use it exclusively but can't because of the restrictive limit.  And see what happens.  Pay the balance off first, don't call in with that request while it's maxed out.

Comment: @quid: I got the impression the customer service reps can't do much regarding whether you're approved for a limit raise or not; is that not the case? When I called to see why my transaction was declined I even asked the guy how much is normal for this card (my limit was absurdly low) and he said "there's no set number, you just have to request whatever you're comfortable with" and "you'll get a decision letter in the mail" which seemed to indicate to me he didn't have any control over it...

Comment: @Mehrdad, It depends on the bank how much authority the person you talk to has.  This is why I didn't post an answer to this question.  All anyone can really do is offer you their opinion about what they would do.  I'd wait 90 days then request an increase.  I wouldn't request a reduction from A because you're not sure B will approve an increase.  If you had a number of cards I'd just cancel one of them but since this is only your second card you don't have a lot of options without potentially putting yourself in a worse position.

Comment: @quid: Oh I have more than 2 cards (if you notice a couple comments ago I was referred to changing the cash limits on 2 other cards from the *same* bank)... I could indeed cancel another card but would that help? People say you should never cancel any cards since it doesn't help your credit score... I feel like I get totally contradictory advice about everything regarding credit lines and card cancellation.

Comment: @Mehrdad, Your question should indicate that you have more than 2 cards.  You get contradictory information because I have 15 years of credit history and don't care if my score fluctuates a little.  I've been declined for cards and line increases, I've also cancelled cards and reduced limits.  This stuff isn't life and death, try something and see what happens.  The worst outcome is you're declined for the increase, the bank tells you why, and you have a hard pull on your report.  If the problem is your total limit, maybe you cancel a card, you wait the 60 or 90 days, then you try again.

Comment: @quid: Yes, I know it's not life or death; I'm just trying to figure out what I can/should do to increase the limit on this card. Better get it right on the first try than fail on the first and have to wait several months/a year before trying again with a decent shot. The credit score thing was only there because my credit score can affect something like this, not because I particularly care about whether it goes up or down per se.

Comment: @Mehrdad, All I'm saying is people say things like "never cancel a credit card because it's *bad* for your credit", as though the outcome will be really bad or irreversible but never speak in terms of severity.  I cancelled a card and it had literally zero impact on my credit score.  I've had hard pulls that had a 5 point impact that disappeared after a month.  If you think lowering another card's limit will help and there won't be a severe impact to your utilization, then do it.

Comment: @quid: Right, so now we're back to square one. You're saying I should lower another card's limit because it will help, and this answer is saying I shouldn't because it will hurt. I have no idea how to tell who is right...

Comment: @Mehrdad, I'm not saying it will help.  I'm saying no one has an answer to this question and you will only get opinions.  This person says it will hurt, but doesn't say how much it will hurt, because they don't know; and claims that bank B doesn't care about your overall available limit which is categorically wrong.  I'm saying IF you think it will help AND cancelling or reducing a card won't materially change your overall utilization you should just do it because IF the outcome is negative, the negative probably wouldn't be that bad anyway.

Comment: @quid: Uhm... "if you think it will help"... isn't that the entire point of my question? If I thought it would help I wouldn't be asking you guys... the point is I could see it going either way, so I'm asking here...

Comment: Some banks care. Some don't. Some want to see responsible usage at high limits and some don't care. What you do depends on how bad you need the limit on B to be higher and your best guess on what they like. Ficoforums may have lots of info about what B likes. Ultimately both answers could be correct depending. There are lots of people with 2-3x their income in available credit

Comment: @Mehrdad, to answer your question, I see nothing here to indicate that Quid has any additional knowledge on the subject.  The choice that will maximize your credit score is pretty clear and outlined in my post.  Your credit score is the main thing the bank will care about, along with the questions they explicitly ask.  If you have a ton of credit elsewhere, that is no skin off the bank's nose.  While they could do anything, I suppose, there's no rational reason for them to prefer you to have less credit elsewhere.  I therefore think my original answer is as good as it can get as it stands now.